# solve trig equation over boundary

Tags: matlab

Firstly, I'm sure a simple answer exists for this, maybe I'm just not wording it right in searching for an answer online.

I'm trying to solve an equation that looks like this:

```
a*x*cot(a*x) == b
```

Where a and b are constants.  Using

```
solve(a*x*cot(a*x) == b, x)
```

I'm getting a result I know is wrong (with the values I'm using for the constants, I'm getting like -227, and it should be something around +160.)  I plotted it up in Mathematica as two separate functions, and they do cross each other right around there, but since the cot part is periodic, they do so many times.

I want to constrain Matlab's search for the solution to a specific interval, such as 0 to 200; how do I do that?

I'm pretty new to Matlab (rather more experienced in Mathematica).

Comment: Which numbers are you using for a and b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the bounds on `x` using [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) with only two requirements

1. The function must be in a "residual" form (i.e., `r(x) = 0`)
2. The residual values at the two bounds must have opposite sign (this guarantees that a root exists within the interval for continuous functions).

So we re-write the function in residual form:

```
r = @(x) a*x*cot(a*x) - b;
```

define the interval

```
% These are just random numbers; the actual bounds should come 
% from the graph the ensures r has different signs a xL and xR
xL = 150;
xR = 170;
```

and solve

```
x = fzero(r,[xL,xR]);
```

---

I see you were trying to use the Symbolic Toolbox for a solution, but since the equation is a non-linear combination of a polynomial and a trigonometric function, there is more than likely no closed form solution.  So I differed to a non-linear, numeric root-finder.

Comment: This worked!  I came across the fzero function today, but didn't know it needed to be in that format, which threw errors when I tried it in the original format.  I got an answer that matches Mathematica's answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried some values and it seems `solve` returns a numeric solution. This is the documented behaviour if no analytic solution is found.

In this case, you may directly call the numeric solver with a matching start value

```
vpasolve(a*x*cot(a*x) == b, x,160)
```

It's not exactly what you asked for, but using your reading from the plot as a start value should do it.

Comment: I tried this (and it is a numerical solution I want, sorry if I wasn't specific on that), but I'm getting "Undefined function 'vpasolve' for input arguments of type 'double'."  The actual equation I'm solving looks like this then:
vpasolve(x*R*cot(x*R) == 1-(R/(2*D)),x,100)
where R and D are constants (I just cleaned it up to it was easier to look at in my question.)